# How to know which param of @RequestMapping is called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

This is my `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```
  @RequestMapping({"/loginBadCredentials", "/loginUserDisabled", "/loginUserNumberExceeded"})
  public String errorLogin(...){        
            ... 
        }
```

Inside the method **errorLogin** , is there a way to know which of the three url was "called"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `HttpServletRequest` as your parameters and use it to find the current request path.

**Update**: Spring also provides `RequestContextHolder`:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
String currentReqUri = attributes.getRequest().getRequestURI();
```

In my opinion, first approach is better and a little more testable.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I already did it, but I was wondering if there was a specific "Spring way" to do it.

Answer (score 3):

you can inject the HttpServletRequest into the method-parameters and then get the called uri.

```
  @RequestMapping({"/loginBadCredentials", "/loginUserDisabled", "/loginUserNumberExceeded"})
  public String errorLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {        
            String uri = request.getRequestURI(); 
            // do sth with the uri here
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I already did it, but I was wondering if there was a specific "Spring way" to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method is to inject HttpServletRequest and get the uri:

```
@RequestMapping({"/loginBadCredentials", "/loginUserDisabled", "/loginUserNumberExceeded"})
public String errorLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {        
        String uri = request.getRequestURI(); 
        // switch on uri what you need to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I already did it, but I was wondering if there was a specific "Spring way" to do it.